# interactive launch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does ROS have a way to interactively start-stop nodes?
For example - taking a bunch of rosnodes and having a start-stop button next to each and showing their output?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10601/interactive-launch/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-07-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Dimitar,

I just started on something called rxlaunch, which does exactly that.  It's still in active development, but may already be useful to you.

[image: image description]

You can get rxlaunch from [its kforge page](https://kforge.ros.org/project/rxlaunch/services/hg/).  Just checkout the mercurial repository and run `rxlaunch.py`.  You may also need to [install PySide](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Linux).

Some things that don't work yet (2011-07-14):

- <strike>It doesn't load parameters, so you should `roslaunch` the launch file first, then use rxlaunch</strike> (fixed 2011-07-14)
- Everything is launched locally
- It's hard-coded to use the master at http://localhost:11311

When things go wrong, just [file a ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/newticket?keywords=rxlaunch&owner=sglaser).

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2011-07-14**:
Note: I just fixed anonymous checkouts.  Just run `hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rxlaunch/hg rxlaunch` to get the code

**Comment by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) on 2011-07-14**:
Thanks for the feature request--I'll put it on my list

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-07-14**:
that is great, I might use it in the near future - meanwhile a UI comment: for some processes it might be usefull to see the standard output as part of the rxlaunch gui.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-27**:
I'm making now `rqt_launch`, a `roslaunch` GUI based on `rqt` framework that's introduced since Groovy. http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_launch. As of today only source install is possible (from http://goo.gl/pC7Mv) but will soon be available in debian pkg.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it does not.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1